# Admin console for hornetq

Tags: hornetq

Is there any sort of admin UI available for hornetQ.
Below are the operations we would like to do with admin UI
I need to monitor the messages in the queue(message content as well)
Purging the messages.
Creating queues

Answer (score 1):

@anoop, you can try jconsole. It will list queue under MBeans. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The HornetQ code-base was donated to the Apache ActiveMQ community several years ago and is now Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.  The latest versions of Apache ActiveMQ Artemis ship with a web-based administration console where you can do things like purge messages and create queues, etc.